# conditionally show input based on a checkbox in react JS/redux-form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I generate a form dynamically from a object.

I have two fields on my Form :
A checkbox pickup_allowed and a Zip text input.

The zip text is mandatory and visible only if pickup_allowed is checked.

How can I show or not the zip text input with redux-form and react js ?

```
const sellingFormFieldDescription = [
  {
    key: 'pickup_allowed',
    type: 'checkbox',
    checkRules: {
      mandatory: false
    } 
  },
  {
    key: 'zip_code',
    type: 'integer',
    checkRules: {
      minValue: 1,
      maxValue: 99999,
      maxLength: 5,
      mandatoryAndVisibleIf: { 
        key: 'pickup_allowed', 
        checked: true
      }
    }
  }
]

class SellingFormFast extends Component {
  render() {
    { sellingFormFieldDescription.map((field,i) => {
      const validate = applyRules(field.checkRules);
      if(field.type === 'checkbox' ){
        return <Field name={field.key} key={i} component={renderCheckbox} validate={validate} />
      } else if (field.type === 'integer') {
        return <Field name={field.key} key={i} component={renderField} validate={validate}/>
      }});
    }
  }
}

export default reduxForm({form: 'sellling_form_fast'})(SellingFormFast)
```

Comment: you aren't returning anything in your `render` for `SellingFormFast`

Comment: @Daniel_L I return a <Field/> component on the render method

Comment: thats inside your map. you need to actually return the map

Comment: @Daniel_L yes it's inside the map and it works like that in react js redux form, it's not the problem. my problem is to show or not a field depending a another field with a dynamic structure

Comment: maybe add a ref to the checkbox and get he value that way